# JQdock issue in IE8 and lower

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I started using JQDock and it works great for me except in < IE8. There the images are all shown in their expended state all crunched together and I don't get the roll over effect. I can't find any other info on this so I am assuming I just fat fingered something as it doesn't seem to be a common problem.

Here's the code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Content/thirdparty/jquery/plugins/jqdock/jquery.jqDock.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var opts =
{ align: 'left',
    bias: 45,
    step: 75,
    size: 55, flow: true
};
    jQuery('#dock').jqDock(opts);
});
//]]>
</script>


<style>
#dock { background: #333 url("/Content/i/dock/pattern.png") repeat top left; width: 72px; border-right: 2px solid #d5d7d7; margin-left: -5px;padding: 0; }
#dock a { font-size: 11px; color: #fbfbf1; border:0; text-decoration: none; }
#dock div.jqDockWrap{ margin:0 auto; }
#dock div.jqDock { cursor:pointer; }
#dock img { padding: 8px 10px; }
#dockWrapper { float:left; width:100px; padding:0; margin:15px 0 0 -5px; }
.corners { margin-left: -11px;padding: 0;margin-bottom:-5px; }
</style>

<div id="dockWrapper" >
<div class="corners"><img src="/Content/i/dock/top.png" width="80" height="15"/>            </div>
<div id="dock">
    <a href="link1" title="Desk"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image1.png" alt="title" title="title" height="80" width="80" /></a>
    <a href="link2" title="title"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image2.png" alt="title" title="title" /></a>
    <a href="link3" title="title"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image3.png" alt="title" title="title" /></a>
    <a href="link4" title="title"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image4.png" alt="title" title="title" /></a>
<!-- others removed for brevity -->
</div>
<div class="corners"><img src="/Content/i/dock/bottom.png" width="80" height="15" /></div>
```

Any thoughts on the issue would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to close the `<div id="dockWrapper" >`  try add `</div>`

```
<div id="dockWrapper" >
<div class="corners"><img src="/Content/i/dock/top.png" width="80" height="15"/>            </div>
<div id="dock">
    <a href="link1" title="Desk"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image1.png" alt="title" title="title" height="80" width="80" /></a>
    <a href="link2" title="title"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image2.png" alt="title" title="title" /></a>
    <a href="link3" title="title"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image3.png" alt="title" title="title" /></a>
    <a href="link4" title="title"><img src="/Content/i/dock/image4.png" alt="title" title="title" /></a>
<!-- others removed for brevity -->
</div>
<div class="corners"><img src="/Content/i/dock/bottom.png" width="80" height="15" /></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE

have you declared the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```